# Hide permanent system Bar Android

Tags: java, android

What is the best way to hide permanent system bar on android?
I want a full-screen app without system bar.
All that I got so far is hide the bar, but if I swipe up it appears.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```