# hide nevigation bar from SystemUI in custom android11 os

Tags: android, navigationbar

have already read the article [How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)
have also tried [Permanently hide Navigation Bar in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26013850/15902516)

But that is not what I want
My question is can I change code from os source which hide navigation bar permanently

such as path:frameworks\base\services\java\com\android\server\SystemServer.java where the main start
and where can I set navigation bar invisible

which in user view they cannot see navigationbar forever  after they power on their device

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution might only work in android 11
yep I will just answer this by myself

to remove the navigation bar on the entire system
the andoird 11 works totally different compare to android 7

they remove PhoneStatusBar.java and combine it into StatusBar.java

both of them are in ..\frameworks\base\packages\SystemUI\src\com\android\systemui\statusbar\phone

in Android7 method people use

```
mWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(mNavigationBarView);
```

but this might not works properly and might cause SystemUI shut down

try use below method to do so
Path ..\SystemUI\src\com\android\systemui\statusbar\NavigationBarController.java

```
@Override
    public void onDisplayRemoved(int displayId) {
        removeNavigationBar(displayId);
    }


Using view to set flag cannot work properly because when you switch window or app the nav bar will appear again
```